# Dataframe, flask, and wtf

Tags: python, pandas, flask, jinja2

I'm utilizing a Flask framework using Blueprints and I have a dataframe that I would like to display.  Typically, the flow of my code is as follows:

Route (flow control / variable calcs) -> Form fields (wtf)  -> .html (jinja2)

In this particular case, it's purely a display function that I'm attempting to execute.  I have successfully read in my csv file to a dataframe, and now i'm potentially ready to go straight to the html display.

But what are your thoughts around the wtf function?  Should I bypass this step entirely?  Would that be "bad form"?

Comment: You don't need to use WTForms if there isn't a form. Just render the dataframe into the template with Jinja2 syntax.

Comment: `wtf` can be useful if you want to get some information from user. If you only want to display `DataFrame` then you may need only `table = df.to_html()` and display it in template using `{{ table | safe }}`